# Generated source for iframe still blocks access to iframe in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

When I want to access DOM elements in a dynamically generated iframe source, I am blocked from accessing it by my browser just as I would be in the case of an iframe loaded from a different location. Is there a way to tell the iframe element that its 'src' attribute is home-brewn? In code:

In the html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <iframe id="my-iframe" ng-src="{{ctrl.renderIframe()}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

In angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$sce', function($sce) {

  var self = this;
  var iframeContent = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(
    '<div id="target">Shoot the target</div>'
  );
  var iframePointer = angular.element('#my-iframe');
  var targetPointer;

  self.renderIframe = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(iframeContent);
  };

  /* Edit: needed a [0] selector */
  iframePointer[0].onload = function() {
    targetPointer = iframePointer.contents().find('#target');
    targetPointer.text('I shot it');
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried using an external source instead, just to see if it works?

Comment: You mean just referencing something like ng-src="http://some.other-address.co.uk" ? It is of course possible to obtain a different location, but the trouble would be the same: trying to read/write individual elements inside the iframe with javascript is prohibited because it's not of the same source.

Comment: I mean instead of dynamically generating the source in Angular, create a new HTML file containing `<div id="target">Shoot the target</div>` and use that as the source on the same origin, then seeing if what you are trying to do works.

Comment: Ah like so. Yes, that does work, although I must admit I forgot to put a [0] selector prior to the onload event handler function. Getting it from the generated src again still does throw the "property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame." error.

Comment: Is there a reason you need an iframe?  Why not just append html to the main document?

Comment: Fair question, but yes, in dealing with email templates I want to put them in a scope of their own where they can behave any way they must without causing (predominantly css) naming conflicts with the page in which you load them. At the same time, I need each email template as-is because I want to serve them to the clients the way they will show up in mail boxes. On top of that, you want to show the edits that users make by showing the changes dynamically in the email template loaded in the iframe. It is a rare occasion, it is true.

Comment: See [MDN <iframe> Cross-origin script API access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access)

Answer (score 1):

After digging some more, [I came across a solution](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/): set the source of the iframe to 'about:blank' and then load the html into the iframe's document body. You then get:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl" id="myApp">
  <iframe id='my-iframe'></iframe>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', [function() {

  var self = this;
  var htmlString = '<div id="target">Shoot the target</div>';
  var iframePointer = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
  var targetPointer;

  iframePointer.src = 'about:blank';

  iframePointer.onload = function() {

    /* Apply the html */
    iframePointer.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
    iframePointer.contentWindow.document.write(htmlString);
    iframePointer.contentWindow.document.close();

    /* Manipulate html */
    targetPointer = iframePointer.contentWindow.document.getElementById('target');
    targetPointer.innerHTML = 'I shot it';

  };

}]);
```

I did have to resort to vanilla stuff, so angular is not really relevant anymore for this. In fact, it sort of flies in the face of angular ethics because it manipulates DOM elements straight. But, it works.

Comment: You should consider [Creating a Custom Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to do the DOM work. And use [Angular's jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) as well.